# How to save Best Time score using NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey guys I'm extremely new to programming and especially with Objective C so please bear with me. I been practicing my skills on an iPhone app project I have been working on and now am stuck on an issue with saving time. I have a simple slider puzzle game that has a timer that increases until you finish the puzzle. the time is represent in this format "00:00". i would like to be able to save the lowest time after completion and present it on the screen on the start of the app for reference on the time to beat. The problem I face however is that it keeps saving the time 0 as the lowest and nothing can beat that.

Below is code of my:

Timer

```
-(void)setTimer
{
    self.secondsCount = 0;
    self.gameCountDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerRun
{
    self.secondsCount++;

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02.f : %02i", round(self.secondsCount / 60), self.secondsCount % 60 ];

    self.timeLabel.text = timerOutput;
}
```

StartGame Button

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    // reset steps

    self.secondsCount=0;
    step = 0;
    [self setTimer];

    // set the view so that it can interact with touches
    [board setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // set the label text to 'reset'
    [startButton setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // initialize the board, lets play!
    [board playWithImage:image andSize:(boardSize.selectedSegmentIndex+3)];
}
```

End of Game

```
 (void)puzzleBoardDidFinished:(PuzzleGameView *)puzzleBoard {

    // add the full image with 0.0 alpha in view
    if(self.secondsCount!=0){
        self.finalTime = self.secondsCount;
        NSLog(@"seconds is: %i",self.secondsCount);
        [self saveTime];

        if(self.finalTime<self.bestTime) {

            NSLog(@"bestTime! is: %i",self.finalTime);
        [self saveTime];
        }
    }
    [self.gameCountDownTimer invalidate];
    self.gameCountDownTimer = nil;

    UIImageView *fullImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    fullImage.frame = board.bounds;
    fullImage.alpha = 0.0;
    [board addSubview:fullImage];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 
                     animations:^{
                         // set the alpha of full image to 1.0

                         fullImage.alpha = 1.0;                    
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // set the view interaction and set the label text

                         NSLog(@"Congrats! You finish this %d x %d puzzle with %d steps", (boardSize.selectedSegmentIndex+3), (boardSize.selectedSegmentIndex+3), step);
                         [board setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                         [startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     }];    
}
```

And Attempt to save the data

```
-(void)saveTime {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:self.secondsCount forKey:@"BestTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

This was in my viewdidload

```
self.bestTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"BestTime"];
    self.bestTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02.f : %02i", round(self.bestTime / 60), self.bestTime % 60 ];
```

As stated before Im pretty new so any advice and recommendations would be awesome. Im definitely eager to learn more about this stuff and would greatly appreciate if you guys could help with the journey. Thank You

Comment: Good that you included code, but please edit your question to only show code that's relevant to the issue.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in saveTime and viewDidLoad and check the value that is going in to/coming out of NSUserDefaults. That should help you pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"BestTime"]` is 0 every time you assign its value to `self.bestTime`.

This code might help:

`if(self.bestTime == 0){
    self.bestTime = finalTime;
}`

Comment: Yes that helped me out thank you :) I actually figured that out before you posted it but forgot to place my answer here. Thanks anyway for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. I'm pretty sure it's just the showing the value in NSLog that is not working.

Change:

```
self.bestTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02.f : %02i", round(self.bestTime / 60), self.bestTime % 60 ];
```

To:

```
self.bestTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02.f : %02i", round(self.bestTime / 60.0f), self.bestTime % 60 ];
```

For float variable: `int / int` yields integer which you are assigning to float and printing it so it's `0.00`.